# iPhone 8 - Pictures associated with contacts disappear

Tags: iphone, photos, contacts

I just upgraded to an iPhone 8 from a 5s. I have photos of those listed as my favorites. Some of the photos won't stay with the associated contact. I open the contact, tapped Edit, Add Photo-> Choose Photo, pick the picture I want, tap Choose, then Done. About 5-7 seconds later, the photo disappears.

My phone and desktop use a Hosted Exchange for mail, contacts, notes etc. I don't use iCloud.
 Any ideas?
DB

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I added my contacts to iCloud, went through the above steps and voila - the contact photos stay associated with their respective contact. I then toggled the contacts off of iCloud.
Thanks-
DB